# Exchange Web Service FolderId for a not well known folder name

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a folder in an Exchange mailbox that is a child of the root (not Inbox).

How do I get the ID of such folder using EWS Managed API?

Only examples I find are those relating to WellKnownFolderNames.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can find all Folders with the `FindFolders` method. Use `WellKnownFolderName.Root` to show all your folders of your Inbox. You have to create a `FolderView` and add the properties you want to see (`ID` and `DisplayName` for example). Set the traversal to `Deep` to find all of your folders. In my example, I'm looking for the folder with the `DisplayName` "Test".

```
// set Server
ExchangeService server = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
server.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
string configUrl = @"https://yourServerAddress.asmx";
server.Url = new Uri(configUrl);

// set View
FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = server.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);

// find specific folder
foreach (Folder f in findFolderResults)
{
    // show FolderId of the folder "Test"
    if (f.DisplayName == "Test")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to search for folders in a specific mailbox create `FolderId` for the specific root folder using `new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, mailbox)` and use that in the `FindFolders` call.

Comment: If you already have an `ExchangeService` instance, here's a function for just the folder-finding part:  https://gist.github.com/eeskildsen/e928472d11ba4723440e763ab5eb8b59. Call like this: `Folder folder = FindFolderByDisplayName(exchangeService, "My Folder Name"); Console.WriteLine(folder.Id);`.

Answer (score 20):

A bit late, but the following is what I used to find my folder:

```
var view = new FolderView(1);
view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
var filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Rejected");
var results = Service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, filter, view);
if (results.TotalCount < 1)
    throw new Exception("Cannot find Rejected folder");
if (results.TotalCount > 1)
    throw new Exception("Multiple Rejected folders");
Rejected = Folder.Bind(Service, results.Folders.Single().Id);
```

**Edit**: Apparently my code did not work on nested heirarchies. I added a line as per cookiemonster's suggested edit.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? A comment would help me know why it got voted down...

Comment: what is the fix for nested folders ?

Comment: @faisantp `view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep`;

Comment: ok actually in my case using your code I can only find default folders not self created ones. Any thought ?

Comment: ok I was looking into my mailbox instead of a sharedfolder. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The answer of seven-ply is valid, but may lead to undesired results.

Suppose you have this structure:

```
Root
--Folder A
----Test
--Folder B
----Test
```

The code he provided would return both test folders.

If you know the path (like Folder B/Test), you can get the folder path iteratively.

See my the method `SetFolderHomePage` in this link: http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/10/05/Setting-the-Homepage-of-an-Exchange-folder-using-the-EWS-Managed-API.aspx.

Comment: I think you should explain a little how your method work in your answer in case the target site get closed. Otherwise, it could look more like a click generator than an answer.