# Find out The Inbox Name in EWS using vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

Anybody know, how can I find out the Name of Inbox-Email Folder in Exchange Web Server (EWS) using vb.net. Depending the local porperties it can be named "Inbox" (engl.), "Posteingang" (german), etc

Thx

Comment: Doesn't `ExchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, ...` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your suggestions I found finally the solution for me:

`Dim strFolderName As String`

`strFolderName = Folder.Bind(objExchange,WellKnownFolderName.Inbox).DisplayName.ToString`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get it:

```
    ExchangeService server = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
    server.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    string configUrl = @"https://yourServerAddress.asmx";
    server.Url = new Uri(configUrl);
    //SetView
    FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
    view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
    view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
    view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
    FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = server.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);
    //find specific folder
    foreach(Folder f in findFolderResults)
    {
        //show folderId of the folder "test"
        if (f.DisplayName == "Test")
            Console.WriteLine(f.Id);
    }
```

Related link:[Exchange Web Service FolderId for a not well known folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912584/exchange-web-service-folderid-for-a-not-well-known-folder-name)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `WellKnownFolderName` enum for that if you only want to access the folder no matter what the name is. If you really need to know the name, open the folder using `WellKnownFolderName`, then retrieve the `DisplayName` attribute.